# Ninject HttpBatchHandler instance

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject, ninject.web

I am trying to create batch handler end point on my ASP.NET WebAPI Project. i did all the configuration using standart .net DefaultHttpBatchHandler.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpBatchRoute(
            routeName: "batch",
            routeTemplate: "api/batch",
            batchHandler: new DefaultHttpBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

Problem with this approach is .NET tries to create controller by itself so it cannot inject dependencies to controllers (it even cannot find a constructor with no parameters).

I searched through but couldn't find anything about this. Is there a Ninject implementation for HttpBatchHandler or do i need to create one?